# Setup Mock to redirect to overloaded method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method called:

```
SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string smtpServer)
```

and an overloaded Method

```
SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, SmtpClient smtpClient)
```

In my unit test I want to setup my `MailService` mock so that when the method `SendMail(string, string, string, string)` is called I want to instead call the overloaded method `SendMail(string, string, string, SmtpClient)` and modify the last parameter to a created `SmtpClient` test object.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to use `.Callback(...)` on your Setup

```
mailServiceMock
  .Setup(m => m.SendMail(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
  .CallBack((string from, string to, string subject, string server) => mailService.SendMail(from, to, subject, server, SomeSMTPServer)
```

More importantly why are you trying to do this?

Normally you would only test that your mock got called with (string, stirng, string, string).

And then another TestClass/Fixture you would test that when you call the

```
(string from, string to, string subject, string smtpServer)
```

overload, you actually call the `SmtpServer` overload with correct details.

**EDIT: After comments**

`mailService` is not a typo.

This will either be:

1. The same mocked isntance (e.g. `mailServiceMock.Object`) if `var mailServiceMock = new Mock<ParentClassNotInterface>{ CallsBase = true }`. This would ofcourse mean your methods **have** to be virtual.
2. An actual concrete implementation of the class/interface.

As to the second note, if I was you I would break this up into one/some/all of the following:

- Unit test that the calling class/method calls `SendServer(string, string, string, string)`. I would use the technique I describe on my blog: [CodePerf[dot]NET - TDD – Mock.Throw Interface Call Verification Technique](http://codeperf.net/tdd-mock-throw-interface-call-verification-technique/)
- Unit test that when you call `SendServer(string, string, string, string)` it calls `SendServer(string, string, string, SmtpServer)` with SmtpServer being set correctly.
- Integration test that SendServer(string, string, string, SmtpServer)` actually sends the email.
- Possibly an end-to-end test (no mocks) that this all works.

Comment: Thanks. And for SomeSMTPServer I can use a SmtpClient object I created in my unit test method?

Comment: Is this a typo that you used mailservice.SendMail instead of  mailServiceMock.SendMail?

Comment: To your question... I want to write an unit test which sends an email with a different outgoing SMTP server than the standard server. But to do this this I need to create the whole SmtpClient object and call the overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest

```
mailServiceMock.Setup(m => m.SendMail(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<SmtpClient>()));
```

With a callback/return bolted on if you want to.

Comment: So when my System Under Test calls the SendMail with 4 string parameters it instead calls the method with 3 string and 1 SmtpClient object? And how to I inject my own SmtpClient object that I created in my unit test method?

Comment: Simplest way is to create a wrapper around SmtpClient implementing an interface. Then write your code against that rather than against SmtpClient. You can then Mock out your interface. Quick and dirty fiddle here to try and illustrate this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsjrsN